# how to get all the headers information in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

when i print like:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(getallheaders());
```

it gives output

```
[Host] => abc.com
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
    [Accept] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.5
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate
    [Cookie] => someth
    [Upgrade-Insecure-Requests] => 1
    [Cache-Control] => max-age=0
    [SM_TRANSACTIONID] => 000000000000000000000000b7857360-1499-58b735e6-68944700-eed22930b94f
    [SM_SDOMAIN] => abc.com
    [SM_REALM] => REALM-BEACONTRACK-DEV-Protect root
    [SM_REALMOID] => 06-000cd148-15d2-18a7-a771-71810afc4027
    [SM_AUTHTYPE] => Form
    ....... many more 

 [Accept] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    [Referer] => http://127.0.0.1:8000
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, sdch, br
    [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.8
    [Cookie] => XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Im1UZ012bXhRQ1VVdEUra1d3Yko4ZEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidnFqN0l6VUVBVjdKd2hWUitHazhlTWN1Z2puSW1LMlZTTU4yYW1GcVwvQWg1aEpkNklZWUkranBIZ3R1UGoxUUdMU1VFWVEzekViWTluSkk1c0FjNlZ3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiIxNGFmMGE1OWQ3OWNlZWY1Y2E4OGQ4MzY1MDg3ZmM2MDY5NzVmYTI2YmE3MzA3YWU2M2U2YjkyOWEzZTMzYWFkIn0%3D; beaconTrack_session=eyJpdiI6ImVWazMyK2JLbXlrN0lxMEVEdE1pTlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiSTdIbVkyWmROSDZBXC8xVmZJdHEycmgwOFpFUm1BNUtWVFNyQjF0MjY5TTV6Qkd1aUFGSEJBcmRrQ3hvM1BxVXdld0tjWlwvcVNEeXcwQmdjWW5yUFwvb1E9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjgzZjRiOGExODc2NmI3Y2JjNDY1MWViMThlZmE0ODlhYjMyYzllMTE1OTNhNjM1NWE1ZDc0NWViZDFkMjA3ZTIifQ%3D%3D
)
```

but when i print using laravel functions like:

`print_r($request->header());` or `print_r($request->headers->all());`

it never print out my required variables in array. it print outs below output

```
Array
(
    [host] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc.com
        )

    [connection] => Array
        (
            [0] => keep-alive
        )

    [cache-control] => Array
        (
            [0] => max-age=0
        )

    [upgrade-insecure-requests] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [user-agent] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
        )

    [accept] => Array
        (
            [0] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
        )

    [accept-encoding] => Array
        (
            [0] => gzip, deflate, sdch
        )

    [accept-language] => Array
        (
            [0] => en-US,en;q=0.8
        )

    [cookie] => Array
        (
            [0] => cookie
        )

)
```

> how i can print all the values in laravel function the same i can do with this `getallheaders()`?

Comment: just because your using laravel does not mean you can't use `getallheaders()`

Comment: only works on apache

Comment: Yes, or the function of which it is an alias, apache_request_headers ( ). Initially, I thought Laravel was hiding some of the headers, but, apparently not; I compared the lists side by side, and everything is accounted for.

Answer (score 23):

An alternative to @Shedokan's answer using Laravel [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections) `transform()` method instead of `array_map`:

```
$headers = collect($request->header())->transform(function ($item) {
    return $item[0];
});
```

This way `$headers` will be a collection so you can then use the `toArray()` method to convert back to an array. Since this is a collection it also has access to any of the other collection methods.

Answer (score 11):

Laravel uses Symphony, which keeps all header values in sub arrays, so we can just map the array and get them out:

```
$get_first = function($x){
    return $x[0];
};
// Same as getallheaders(), just with lowercase keys
print_r(array_map($get_first, $request->headers->all()));
```

**Note:** All keys are lowercase

Answer (score 4):

You can use below code:

```
$header = app('request')->header('header_name', 'default_header_value');
```

when `$request` is not available.

Comment: Or just `request()` too.