# how to prevent redirection to a domain from other domains

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, redirect, cpanel

Recently found out that there are other domain names pointing to my Laravel website.

Suppose I have a Laravel website `abc.com`. If someone browse for `xyz.com` and it redirects to my site `abc.com`. But I want to prevent this.

Is there any way to do this in Laravel.

Comment: See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542061/how-to-get-all-the-headers-information-in-laravel-5-4) and check for the `Referer` header. Or the `Host` header if they just pointed their domain to your machine.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca.....I want to prevent this redirection.

Comment: You can't. It's their domain, it's out of your control. You can only decide what to do once the redirect has happened.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca...okay. so is there any way that If any domain redirect I can redirect those domain to a specific page ?

Comment: Once you determined that the request is coming from somewhere else you can [set the Location header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643718/location-headers-in-laravel) to cause a redirect.